# Make readonly the input part of jQuery Mobile slider

Tags: jquery, mobile, slider

For these sliders: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/sliders/

Is there a way to set the number input box next to the slider to a readonly state? I don't want it to be possible for a user to modify the number directly (they should only use the slider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, add readonly to the input tag

```
<input type="number" data-type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-slider-input" readonly>
```